# Spring Boot start/stop tasks dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron

I have a Spring Boot application, I need to expose 2 endpoints to start and stop scheduled task. The cron/fixed delay expression is defined in database.This configuration is per client.For example if client A calls the start API, I need to start a scheduled task based on the config defined in the database for that client A. The logic inside the task is same for all the clients.

My question is, any no of clients can call start and stop APIs, So how to start the task dynamically when start api is called and also stop the task (only that particular client's task not all ) when the client calls the stop API

`

```
@RestController
class SchedulerController {

   
    @Autowired
    TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;

    @RequestMapping("start")
    ResponseEntity<Void> start(@RequestParam String clientId) {
        String fixedDelay = "get it from database for the provided client";
        scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.schedule(excuteLogic(clientId), fixedDelay);
       // generate a task id and save in db against clientid 
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping("stop")
    ResponseEntity<Void> stop(@RequestParam String clientId) {
        // get the taskid from database for the clientId
       // stop the task
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private Runnable excuteLogic(String clientId) {
    
        return () -> {
          // logic goes here
          };
    }
}
```

Planning to generate a task id and save it in the database against clientid ,but not sure how to stop particular task scheduled for the provided client.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, since you have a fixed delay, I would save myself the headache and just keep that task running always and depending on a simple flag either return from the worker or continue. So something along the lines of:

```
@RequestMapping("start")
    ResponseEntity<Void> start(@RequestParam String clientId) {
        //either start the task on app startup or start it here if not started
        myFlagService.enableScheduler(clientId);
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@RequestMapping("stop")
ResponseEntity<Void> stop(@RequestParam String clientId) {
    myFlagService.disableScheduler(clientId);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
//the scheduled task
private void myWorkerFunction() {
    if (!myFlagService.isSchedulerEnabled(clientId)) {
        return;
    }
// do work 
}
```

Comment: The fixed delay is not same for all clients.Its configured on the database

Comment: @SST I don't think that's a problem, start the task inside the start API if it's not already started?